# makeing listbox as dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net

I tried to select multiple option from dropdown list for I required list box but it should be look like a dropdownlist. Please tell me the css for listbox to use it as dropdownlist.

css for listbox

```
 .setScroll
        {    
                scrollbar-base-color: WhiteSmoke;
                scrollbar-3dlight-color: Blue;
                scrollbar-arrow-color: Red;
                scrollbar-track-color: WhiteSmoke;
                scrollbar-shadow-color: Blue;
                scrollbar-darkshadow-color: WhiteSmoke;
                scrollbar-face-color: WhiteSmoke;
            }
```

I wanna select multiple option and I add this control dynamically from code behind file

Comment: http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/1591/multiselect-dropdown-in-aspnet-40-using-csharp

Answer (score 0):

markup:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cboItems" runat="server" />
```

Code behind:

```
List<ListItem> items = new List<ListItem>();
for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
{
    ListItem item = new ListItem();
    item.Text = string.Format("this is a very very long item text corresponding to the  number {0}", i);
    item.Value = i.ToString();
    items.Add(item);
}
cboItems.DataSource = items;
cboItems.DataBind();
// after data bind is complete
cboItems.Attributes["style"] = "width: 100px; max-width: 100px";
```

Comment: In that case i can select only one option I wanna select multiple option and I add this control dynamically from code beihind file